# How would I automatically move someone back to a channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So, basically I have some code setup and I don't see the issue with the code. But basically what I want it to do is if the previous voice channel of the member that switched channels was "DO NOT DISTURB" it will move them back to the "DO NOT DISTURB" voice channel. What have I done wrong? I get 0 errors in console.

```
    client.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (oldState, newState) => {
        let newUserChannel = newState.channel;
        let oldUserChannel = oldState.channel;

       if(oldUserChannel.id === "894024223088050176") {
                    var dndChannel = oldState.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.type === "voice" && ch.name === "DO NOT DISTURB")
                    newState.member.voice.setChannel(dndChannel)
                }
      });
```

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: I'm not really sure so I won't post it as an answer but try `newState.voice.setChannel(dndChannel.id)`

Comment: Do you have the `GUILD_VOICE_STATES` intent?

Comment: I do not have that intent but I've used other events related to voice channels such as disconnecting a user and such so, should that matter? @GentleAutumnRain

Comment: I'm using djs v12 @MrMythical

Comment: Adding the intent doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: So, I added the intents correctly and everything works fine but the code I sent above still does not work. I have no errors in console. @GentleAutumnRain

Answer (score 0):

Double check if your channelid in the if condition is right and use

```
Guild.channels.fetch(channelId)
```

insted of `Guild.channels.cache.find()`.